# Determinant of a matrix having diagonal and subdiagonal entries zero

Tags: determinants

I have found the determinant of the following matrix of order $n\ge3$ using some elemetary operations 
$$\begin{bmatrix}0& 1 & 1& \dots & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1& \ddots & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & 1 \\ \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 0 \end{bmatrix}_{n\times n},$$ that is, a matrix which have diagonal, subdiagonal entries zero and rest of entries are equal to 1. Its determinant comes out to be equal to $$(-1)^n\Big(\lfloor\frac{n-2}{2}\rfloor\Big),$$ where,  $\lfloor.\rfloor$ is the floor function. Now, I want to find determinant of the following matrix 
$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}0& -1 & 1& \dots & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1& \ddots & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & 1 \\ \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & -1\\ 1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 0 \end{bmatrix}_{n\times n},$$ that is, a matrix having diagonal and subdiagonal entries zero. Superdiagonal elements are -1 and rest of the entries are equal to 1.

Comment: Does $0,0,1,3,6,2,15,53,44,92,349,503,802,2310,4347$ match your calculations?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Please let me know the steps.

Comment: I don't know the pattern. It's not in the OEIS yet. I just asked Mathematica to compute the first few values and thought they might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to give a different explicit solution.  From the problem formulation of answer 1,  $$\det(A+uu^T)=(1+u^TA^{-1}u).\det(A).$$ From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix), we need to solve some recursive expressions, in order to calculate the determinant and inverse of $A$. I solve these recursive expressions using roots of their characteristic equations. For the determinant of $A$, recursive expression is $$f_n=-f_{n-1}-2f_{n-2},\ \ \ \ \ f_0=1,\ f_{-1}=0.$$  Roots of the resulting characteristic equation $x^2+x+2=0,$ are $$ s_1=\frac{-1}{2}+ \frac{\iota \sqrt{7}}{2},\ \ s_2=\frac{-1}{2}- \frac{\iota \sqrt{7}}{2}.$$ Hence,   $$\det(A)=f_n=r_1.s_1^n+r_2.s_2^n,$$ where, using initial conditions $$r_1=\frac{1}{2} +\frac{\iota }{2\sqrt{7}},\ \ r_2=\frac{1}{2} -\frac{\iota }{2\sqrt{7}}.$$ 
Now, to calculate $A^{-1}$ we need to solve following recursive expressions $$g_i=-g_{i-1}-2g_{i-1}, \ \text{for} \ \ i=2, 3\dots,n,\ \  g_0=1,\ g_1=-1$$    $$ h_i=-h_{i+1}-2h_{i+2}, \ \text{for} \ \ i=n-1,\dots,1, \ \ h_{n+1}=1,\ h_{n}=-1.$$ Similar to $f_n$, solving these recursive expressions we get $$g_i=r_{1}.s_1^i+r_{2}.s_2^i.$$ And, $$h_i=r_{h1}.s_1^{n-i}+r_{h2}.s_2^{n-i},$$ where, $$r_{h1}=\frac{-1}{2}-\frac{3}{2\iota\sqrt(7)},\ \ \ r_{h2}=\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{3}{2\iota\sqrt(7)}.$$ Entries of $A^{-1}$ are clearly given by $g_i, h_i$ ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix)).

$$A^{-1}_{ij}=\begin{cases}\frac{2^{j-i}g_{i-1}h_{j+1}}{g_n}
 & \mbox{if $i\le j$}
\\ \frac{g_{j-1}h_{i+1}}{g_n} &\mbox{if $j< i$}
\end{cases}.$$

Comment: I think it is not much different from Amdeberhan's answers. This answer contains a step by step procedure.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a principal solution (some details left for you).

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ *tridiagonal* matrix such that all its entries consisting of zeros except for those on (i) the main and subdiagonals are $-1$; (ii) superdiagonals are $-2$.

Let $u$ be the column vector all entries are $1$ so that $uu^T$ is an $n\times n$ matrix of all $1$'s. This way, your matrix becomes $A+uu^T$. Now, apply the [Matrix Determinant Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) to obtain
$$\det(A+uu^T)=(1+u^TA^{-1}u)\cdot\det(A).$$
The good news is: determinants and inverses of tridiagonal matrices are calculable (see [this on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix)). For example, in the present case
$$f_n:=\det(A)=(-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}2\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n-k}k2^k.$$
Also, observe that the quantity $u^TA^{-1}u$ is the sum of all entries of the inverse matrix $A^{-1}$.

**UPDATE.** Since you still ask about the inverse and etc, I've computed your determinant
\begin{align} \det(A+uu^T)&=f_n+\sum_{i\leq j}^{1,n}2^{j-i}f_{i-1}f_{n-j}+\sum_{j<i}^{1,n}f_{j-1}f_{n-i} \\
&=f_n+\sum_{i=1}^nf_{i-1}f_{n-i}+\sum_{j<i}^{1,n}(1+2^{i-j})f_{j-1}f_{n-i}.
\end{align}

Comment: I am trying to solve the recurrence relations for determinant and inverse of A using characteristic equation. Your expression for determinant is more simpler and fancy, but I do not know how you arrived to this expression?.  It will be better for me if you elaborate this or provide me some references where I can read about such solutions.

Comment: Very nice! Do you suppose a non-recursive formula is possible?

Comment: One more thing. I have found the determinant of A using characteristic equation of recurrence relation. But, in order to calculate inverse of A, I need to solve a recurrence of function \phi, where each \phi depends on higher index \phi. So, I don't think characteristic equation is good way to solve \phi. That is why I am more interested in your way of solving recurrence.

Comment: Denoting $\det(A)$ by $f(n)$, we also have the recurrence $$ f(n)=-f(n-1)-2f(n-2). $$

Comment: @RichardStanley, I have already solved the recurrence for f(n). I was hoping for some expression for inverse of A, like expression for det of A given in above answer.